# ASP.Net LinkButton and iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, linkbutton

I have found out that embedded `UIWebView`'s do not cause postbacks if the button is a asp.net `LinkButton`, but they work fine with `Button`'s. Safari causes postback as normal for `LinkButton`'s.

Are there any workarounds to this?

Code snippet:

```
vwWebView.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (url)));
```

(we're using monotouch but this seems an iOS issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the default user agent for the UIWebView was making IIS not send the javascript to the content items. The solution is to manually set the user agent of the webview to that of mobile safari.

Here's the code that makes it happen:

```
static public void SetUserAgent(UIWebView webview) {
    var agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A403 Safari/8536.25";
    var webDocumentView = new NSObject(Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend(webview.Handle,
                                                                     (new Selector("_documentView").Handle)));
    var webView = webDocumentView.GetNativeField("_webView");
    Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(webView.Handle, 
                                       (new Selector("setCustomUserAgent:")).Handle,                        
                                       (new NSString(agent)).Handle);
}
```

This post provided the solution:
http://blog.reinforce-lab.com/2010/06/monotouchuiwebviewhowtochangeuseragent.html

The following post doesn't work. It only cutomizes the first request, but not of susequent browsing: http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/seting-UIWebview-user-agent-objectiveC-question-td3807602.html